Find a basis that belongs to two arbitrary complete flags
The question is as below:
We say a basis of $V_n(F)$ belongs to a complete flag ($V_1$,...,$V_n$) if each $V_i$ contains exactly one element of the basis that is not in $V_{i-1}$.
(a)Show that if ($V_1$,...,$V_n$) and ($W_1$,...,$W_n$) are complete flags on $V_n(F)$,then there is a basis of $V_n(F)$ that belongs to both flags.
(b)Use part (a) to give a different proof of the Bruhat decomposition theorem.
At the beginning I thought the standard basis of $V_n(F)$ is the right answer,but soon I found it's wrong if the basis of $V_1$ is like $(1\,1\,...\,1)^T$.I think the basis of $V_1$ and the basis of $W_1$ must be contained in the right basis,but I can't construct the whole basis.Please help me,thanks.
